# How to tell oracle to sort by a specific sort order passed in from java?

Tags: java, sql, oracle, sorting

Here's what I need to be able to do.

I have a List in java which I can convert to comma separate string of IDs like so "3,4,5,6,1,2"

I wonder if there's way to pass that string to oracle and have sql code sort based on that string's sort order?

So this query:

```
select t.id
from t_test t
```

Would result in this order

```
ID
3
4
5
6
1
2
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you can modify the query in java, you could do something like this:

```
SELECT t.id
FROM t_test t
ORDER BY DECODE(t.id, 3, 'A', 'B') ASC,
         DECODE(t.id, 4, 'A', 'B') ASC,
         DECODE(t.id, 5, 'A', 'B') ASC,
         DECODE(t.id, 6, 'A', 'B') ASC,
         DECODE(t.id, 1, 'A', 'B') ASC,
         DECODE(t.id, 2, 'A', 'B') ASC;
```

You have to put a decode in the order by clause for each element in the list. The second parameter in each decode is one element of the list.

Comment: Yeah, I just noticed the same thing and it seems to be working!

Comment: This looks good. But does this mean that order by is applied for the number of times for which decode() is used?

Comment: @Yash the order by clause is only applied once. This is basically the same than `ORDER BY column1 ASC, column2 DESC, ...`. If the order by clause where applied several times, the last time would override the previous ones.

Answer (score 2):

Something like this:

```
with ordered_ids as (
  select to_number(regexp_substr ('3,4,5,6,1,2','[^,]+',1,level)) as id, level as sort_order
  from dual
  connect by regexp_substr ('3,4,5,6,1,2','[^,]+',1,level) is not null
)
select t.id
from t_test t 
  join ordered_ids oi on oi.id = t.id
order by oi.sort_order;
```

You can probably make the literal `'3,4,5,6,1,2'` a parameter for a PreparedStatement but I haven't tested that.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's possible. You can only use ascending or descending order in queries. But what you can do is to use a prepared statement like this `select * from t_test t where t.id = ?` and run this for each ID in your list and add the result to a result list.

You could also try to do this with a stored procedure whose parameter would be the list of IDs

**EDIT**

Another idea is to use IN operator on small chunks of your ID-list (maybe 10 in each). As this will return results in unspecified order, you could write a custom comparator or another class that brings this list into your specified order. Then you can concatenate all sub-lists into one result list. For a list with 100 entries and batch size 10 you would only need 10 DB queries + some time for reordering

Answer (score 0):

```
select t1 from (select t.id t1 from t_test t order by t.id asc);
```

Comment: what technology are you using for database access?

Answer (score 0):

In hibernate u can do -

```
public String getResult(String sortOrder){
    SQLQuery query = getSession().createSQLQuery("select t from ( select t.id t from t_test t order by t.id=:sortOrder").addScalar("name", Hibernate.STRING);    
    query.setString("sortOrder", sortOrder);
    return (String)query.uniqueResult();
}
```