# SQL Order By in oracle custom order by

Tags: sql, oracle

I had a requirement like
select * from USER where firstname IN 
('nexus',
'samsung',
'apple');

On executing this query , i get results based on insertion order of rows in database.But i need the results exactly same way, i given for IN parameter.
for ex : the above query should give results like

---

nexus
samsung
apple

---

and not any other order like.
samsung
nexus
apple

What can i use with the above query to get selection results in the order i given?

Comment: Similar question (restricted to Java): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10813767/how-to-tell-oracle-to-sort-by-a-specific-sort-order-passed-in-from-java

Comment: Similar question (for MySQL, not helpful for Oracle): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2813884/how-do-you-keep-the-order-using-select-where-in

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One method is to use `case`:

```
order by (case when firstname = 'nexus' then 1
               when firstname = 'samsumg' then 2
               when firstname = 'apple' then 3
          end)
```

Another method that has less typing:

```
order by instr(',nexus,samsung,apple,', ',' || name || ',')
```

Comment: Is there any other way, as i have around 100 to 200 firstnames for a select statement.Its more difficult to add then 1,2 for each firstnames.

Comment: I don't think there is a good way for Oracle. How much data do you have? If in the low thousands, probably better to sort client-side in application code.

Comment: @srinivas . . . Where do the names come from?  If they are already in another table or the result of a query, then that would simplify this query.

Comment: I will get the names from excel sheet

Comment: I'd thought, Gordon's `order by instr(',nexus,samsung,apple,', ',' || name || ',')` to save you from the typing. ?? Alternatively, you could number the items (easy in Excel), and then use a regex to assemble the `case`… Or turn the numbered items into an auxiliary table in the database to be used for a `JOIN` based sort criterion. Either of these will require rework if you have to add items not just to the end of the ordered list…

Comment: "i have around 100 to 200 firstnames for a select statement" - how are you passing those names to the IN clause?

Comment: @APC, i will get from excel and format it in notepad to add quotes and pass to that IN clause.